# How to install AWX on RHEL 7 without Docker?

Tags: yum, rhel7, ansible-tower

When I follow this guide to install AWX on RHEL without docker: http://yallalabs.com/devops/how-to-install-ansible-awx-without-docker-centos-7-rhel-7/

https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/mrmeee/awx/repo/epel-7/mrmeee-awx-epel-7.repo has been renamed. Then I got this one: https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/mrmeee/ansible-awx/repo/epel-7/mrmeee-ansible-awx-epel-7.repo, download it and set it to `/etc/yum.repos.d/awx-rpm.repo`.

I run this command to install it

```
yum install -y ansible-awx
```

Got a `Requires: rh-python36-runtime` error.

```
...
Error: Package: rh-python36-social-auth-app-django-3.1.0-1.noarch (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:nsdc92:ansible-awx)
           Requires: rh-python36-python(abi) = 3.6
Error: Package: rh-python36-oauthlib-3.1.0-1.noarch (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:nsdc92:ansible-awx)
           Requires: rh-python36-runtime
Error: Package: ansible-awx-9.1.1.211-1.el7.x86_64 (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:nsdc92:ansible-awx)
           Requires: rh-postgresql10-postgresql-devel
Error: Package: rh-python36-ansible-runner-1.4.4-1.noarch (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:nsdc92:ansible-awx)
           Requires: rh-python36-python(abi) = 3.6
Error: Package: rh-python36-websocket_client-0.57.0-1.noarch (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:nsdc92:ansible-awx)
           Requires: /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python3
Error: Package: rh-python36-django-oauth-toolkit-1.1.3-1.noarch (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:nsdc92:ansible-awx)
           Requires: rh-python36-runtime
Error: Package: ansible-awx-9.1.1.211-1.el7.x86_64 (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:nsdc92:ansible-awx)
           Requires: rh-python36-idna
Error: Package: rh-python36-kombu-4.6.7-1.noarch (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:nsdc92:ansible-awx)
           Requires: rh-python36-runtime
Error: Package: rh-python36-django-jsonfield-1.2.0-1.noarch (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:nsdc92:ansible-awx)
           Requires: rh-python36-python(abi) = 3.6
Error: Package: rh-python36-django-polymorphic-2.1.2-1.noarch (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:nsdc92:ansible-awx)
           Requires: rh-python36-runtime
Error: Package: ansible-awx-9.1.1.211-1.el7.x86_64 (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:nsdc92:ansible-awx)
           Requires: rh-python36-python-logstash
Error: Package: rh-python36-jaraco.functools-3.0.0-1.noarch (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:nsdc92:ansible-awx)
           Requires: rh-python36-python(abi) = 3.6
Error: Package: rh-python36-twilio-6.35.1-1.noarch (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:nsdc92:ansible-awx)
           Requires: rh-python36-python(abi) = 3.6
Error: Package: rh-python36-django-auth-ldap-2.1.0-1.noarch (copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:nsdc92:ansible-awx)
           Requires: rh-python36-python(abi) = 3.6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried to install `rh-python36`

```
# yum install rh-python36
Loaded plugins: search-disabled-repos
No package rh-python36 available.
```

When run `subscription-manager` command to prepare install `rh-python36`, got error

```
# subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sbin/subscription-manager", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('subscription-manager==1.21.10', 'console_scripts', 'subscription-manager')()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/subscription_manager/scripts/subscription_manager.py", line 85, in main
    return managercli.ManagerCLI().main()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/subscription_manager/managercli.py", line 2667, in main
    ret = CLI.main(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/subscription_manager/cli.py", line 183, in main
    return cmd.main()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/subscription_manager/managercli.py", line 467, in main
    self.cp = self.cp_provider.get_consumer_auth_cp()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/subscription_manager/cp_provider.py", line 110, in get_consumer_auth_cp
    restlib_class=self.restlib_class)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rhsm/connection.py", line 783, in __init__
    info = utils.get_env_proxy_info()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rhsm/utils.py", line 224, in get_env_proxy_info
    info = parse_url(proxy_info, default_port=DEFAULT_PROXY_PORT)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rhsm/utils.py", line 200, in parse_url
    raise ServerUrlParseErrorPort(local_server_entry)
rhsm.utils.ServerUrlParseErrorPort
```

> Ref: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1519803

Comment: Are you using CentOS 7? I have just checked and `yum install centos-release-scl` is offering to install version 2-3.el7.centos, from repository `extras`. Check repos, is CentOS-Base/extras enabled?

Comment: @dexter Sorry, it's RHEL 7.

Comment: Then you probably need to enable RH-SCL repo. I dig something, try to run `yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms`. Here is the [link](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-python36/).

Comment: Thank you. But still can't install `yum install rh-python36` due to `file://opt/rh-devsuite-repo/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /rh-devsuite-repo/repodata/repomd.xml"`.

Comment: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel/

Comment: Putting link without comment or any additional information is not very useful. I missed to ask at the beginning, are you paying for RHEL? Do you have subscription? If yes, than you should check RH knowledge base, and this problem is covered. If you don't have subscription, switch to CentOS. Running RHEL for "free" is bad idea.

Comment: @dexter Thanks. I tried to use `subscription-manager` to add source, but failed. I added some details in the bottom of the question.

Comment: You need to connect to the Internet (or a local Satellite server) to enable the repo. Your error indicates you have specified a wrong proxy server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed ansible-awx successfully, using these steps:

```
yum install centos-release-scl
yum install rh-python36
yum install ansible-awx
```

Comment: This may work for CentOS, but not for RHEL.